# Encode text files with Dos\Windows and encoded in UTF-8 from PHP

Tags: php, file-io, utf-8

Im having an issue creating a text file on linux formatted as Dos\Windows and encoded in UTF-8.

What Im doing is this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $product =  $row['products_id']
  . ' ' . $row['products_name']
  . ' ' . $row['manufacturers_name']
  . ' ' . $row['products_model']
  //. ' ' . $row['products_sku']
  . ' ' . zen_href_link('product_info', 'cPath=' . $cPath .  '&products_id=' . $row['products_id']) 
  . ' ' . number_format($row['products_price'],2)
  . ' ' . strip_tags(zen_get_products_description($row['products_id']))
  . ' ' . HTTP_SERVER . '/' .DIR_WS_IMAGES . $row['products_image']
  . ' ' . 'electronics'
  . "\r\n";
 $product = utf8_encode($product);
 fwrite($fh, gzencode($product,9));
```

I was under the impression "\r\n" and the encoding as its done is all thats needed. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you want to be gz-encoding it record by record like that.

If you need it to be gzipped, consider collating it then writing once at the end, or gzipping the file post creation.

```
$productList = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $product =  $row['products_id']
  . ' ' . $row['products_name']
  . ' ' . $row['manufacturers_name']
  . ' ' . $row['products_model']
  //. ' ' . $row['products_sku']
  . ' ' . zen_href_link('product_info', 'cPath=' . $cPath .  '&products_id=' . $row['products_id']) 
  . ' ' . number_format($row['products_price'],2)
  . ' ' . strip_tags(zen_get_products_description($row['products_id']))
  . ' ' . HTTP_SERVER . '/' .DIR_WS_IMAGES . $row['products_image']
  . ' ' . 'electronics'
  . "\r\n";

  $productList .= $product;
}

fwrite($fh, gzencode(utf8_encode($product),9));
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `"\r\n"` is correct. The `utf8_encode()` is redundant, if the database table already contains UTF-8. But the real problem I see is that you should wrap only the concatenation of the $product variable in the `while {...}` loop. You cannot restart the `gzencode` for each line and write chunks into the file. This will lead to an error when you try to open it. Instead of calling gzencode multiple times, simply open your output file with `gzopen()` instead of `fopen()`.